# Data encrypted with the private key can be decrypted only with the public key.

Tags: iphone

I was reading [Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Concepts](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/02concepts/concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH204-TP9)

from ios developer library. In this article when i read this line "Data encrypted with the private key can be decrypted only with the public key, and vice versa.".

i was stuck. how this can be possible?
I think Data encrypted with the public key can be decrypted with the private key.

Is this typo or am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encryption operation is same as the decryption operation.

Most public key encryption relies on the fact that **same** operation with the two keys produces the plain text again.

So using them in wrong order will still give back the original data.

But encrypting with private key means that **everyone** will be able to decrypt it - as the the decryption is done with **public** key. Almost certainly not what you want! :)

However using the keys in reverse, is what's done in digital signatures. So not entirely useless. :)

Answer (score 0):

No this is not a typo. In [Asymmetric cryptographic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) algorithms(ex.RSA) we use two keys. The keys are a pair.

One key in the pair is public key and it is shared. Private key is secret.

if you encrypt with the one key , other key can decrypt it.

If you use public key to encrypt, only the holder of private key can decrypt. This ensures confidentiality.

On the other hand, if private key is used for encryption, it is called [digital signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature). It is used for authentication.